# Java Timer help?

Tags: java, timer

I need to make a Timer with java which runs infinite times, I need to let the timer run each 2 seconds, how would I do this?

Comment: infinite times? You'll be here for a while!

Comment: Google Java Timer gets you the Timer class in Java, why not use that? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: @Roy I tried to do that, but I didn't figure it out, I tried doing: Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new TimerHandler()); , but it gave me an error I couldnt fix myself.

Comment: Well to be honest the Java Timer is overly complicated when compared to the C# one, but MacroS gives a good example, and Java Timer Tutorial would also have given you plenty of good examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a ScheduledExecutorService

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); 
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do something.
    }
}, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`scheduleAtFixedRate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

```
long delay = 1000;
long period = 2000;
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            // Task here ...
        }
    }, delay, period);
```

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService` is the better option. Read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29), and you'll know why.

Comment: I don't understand why. Could you please add a brief explanation?

Comment: If the task takes longer than the `period` to finish, subsequent tasks will begin to queue up and once that task finishes, those queued up tasks will fire in rapid succession and cause erratic behavior. This does not happen with `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: @sthupahsmaht: I see. Thank you for explaining that. I must remember this for the future!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Timer implements Runnable {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.run();
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        //do something cool            
       try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //handle interrupt
        }
    }
}
```

}

Something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) before for similar functionality and it has worked well for me.